# Setting up Confluence on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, confluence, isapi-filters

I want to get my Conflunce wiki be accessed through specific dns name, "mysrv" for an example.
But on mysrv server there is IIS7, hosting several sites. There are separate dns' for each site.
OS on mysrv is Windows Server 2008 x64.
Confluence is java app, hosted by tomcat.

So, I need:
|| dns || app ||
mysrv -> Confluence
app1.mysrv -> IIS7, site app1
app2.mysrv -> IIS7, site app2

By default Confluence uses TomCat. I read that TomCat can't share ports. So, probably I have to host Confluence under IIS. It's possible and even described on Attlassian's site [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+up+Confluence+with+IIS).

I've followed all steps from the doc. With no luck. I've got x64 isapi_redirect. Turn on executing permissions. Then add (absent in the doc) mapping "*" to isapi_redirect.dll .

But I get error from IIS while trying access "mysrv" url:

```
Module IsapiModule 
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler tomcat 
Error Code 0x80004005 
Requested URL http://mysrv/ 
Physical Path c:\prog\Confluence 
Logon Method Anonymous
```

"tomcat" is name of isapi_redirect.dll isapi filter.

I'll be appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it is possible, doesn't mean it's a good idea. Confluence/Atlassian is a heavily Tomcat/Linux focused company, so fixing IIS issues will be the last item on their todo list. I would recommend getting a separate IP and run it under Tomcat.

If that's not an option, then you can put Tomcat on port 8080 or something and then in IIS set up a redirect (ie., confluence.mydomain.com to confluence.mydomain.com:8080).

Comment: Ok, how to set up TomCat on separate IP and having IIS on another IP ?

Comment: Google for tomcat and IP binding. There is a configuration file in tomcat where you specify what IP to bind to.

Comment: I've found. But some other troubles appear. I've created another question - http://serverfault.com/questions/35650/setting-up-iis7-and-tomcat-on-single-machine-with-multiple-ip