# IIS SSL is taking all IPs although it is told not to

Tags: iis, ssl, ip-address

I have a testing system where IIS Express on Windows 7 SSL website has to live together with Cerberus FTP server SSL website (Cerberus FTP has a built-in web server for HTTP uploads).

I have set up Windows to use two IPs from my router

- 192.168.1.128 (for IIS SSL Web Site, using a self-generated SSL certificate for now)
- 192.168.1.129 (for Cerberus FTP built-in SSL Web Site)

In IIS I have set web site binding to use only the IP 192.168.1.128. But still when I launch Cerberus, it says - cannot bind 192.168.1.129:443.

I tested in Firefox - indeed, when I go to 192.168.1.129 (or even localhost), I do not get “Unable to connect“ page as expected, but “The connection was reset” instead. IIS is still occupying those IPs, although it is not serving the website on those IPs.

When I stop the IIS website, Cerberus FTP Website launches without problems. But then I cannot launch IIS web site, it tells - "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

**Why is IIS SSL web site still occupying all IPs?**

Comment: Can you post the output of `netsh http show sslcert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because IIS is a pro tool that tries to be efficient.

It does ONE binding to ALL addresses for the port number, then sorts things out internally in teh binding.

You do not want it? Set DisableSocketPooling.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892847

or b etter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc307219(VS.85).aspx

Basically, IIS uses http.sys - which any serious tool shou,d so a shame in the direction of Cerberus for ignoring windows core mechanisms - and you have to tell http.sys to only liten to specific addresses.

[Setting up IIS7 and TomCat on single machine with multiple IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/35650/setting-up-iis7-and-tomcat-on-single-machine-with-multiple-ip)

Comment: Thanks, netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=192.168.1.128 and
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1 did the trick, now IIS serves only on localhost and that other single IP.

Comment: Again, this is not "IIS". IIS does not open a http socket at all - since Windows 7 I think this is part of the kernel. And the kernel - rightly - thinks that software running on windows should be writte nby competent people and use https.sys to read http streams ;)